# jQuery Ajax works on XAMPP localhost but not on Linux Server

Tags: jquery, ajax, localhost, undefined

Hope someone can help. I really dont have a clue as to why its doing this.

From what Ive read it happens when the file you are calling is external to the site. My ajax call is local. i also read that it could be to do with the case of directories. WIndows ignores case whilst Linux doesnt. However ive checked and re-checked and it all matches :(

Heres my jquery code:

```
this.extraInfo = function(){
$.ajax({
    url : 'lib/ajax/foo.inc.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data: {
        foo : bar
    },
    success : function(data){
        alert('success');

        if (data.error === true)
            alert('error1');
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('error2');
    }
});
```

};

It does throw the errorThrown flag and when checking its content via an alert it says undefined.

Looking at the firebug console the Ajax doest even fire. Yet the function as a whole and the ajax request are being run as the alert returns error2

The exact same code runs fine on my XAMPP local host. I thought it might be something in my htaccess so I deleted all rules etc in there, still no joy

Would appreciate any help, im stumped :(

Comment: What happens when you goto 'lib/ajax/foo.inc.php', in a browser, does it throw an exception? or error?

Comment: No error whatsoever. I've also put in an echo statement. That prints fine as well when the file is accessed directly in a browser. Yet via the Ajax it just refuses.

Comment: the data your trying to send through is it an array?

Comment: Manually replace the relative path with full to test

Comment: Ive just been looking in the Net tab in firebug and its because it cant find the file for some reason:

Failed to load source for: http://xx.co.uk/lib/ajax/foo.inc.php'

Anybody have any ideas as to why this may happen. Their is a 301 re-direct in htaccess but even when i remove all htaccess it still has the same error.

Ohh the data is not an array. Just string values :)

Comment: @Zlatev . Thanks for your tip. I did put an absolute path in and it seems to work fine now, strange. So im guessing it is to do my my 301 re-direct or something else that is denying it permission. Hmmmm

Comment: D'Oh I didnt restart lol. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You're making a POST request.
You need to make a GET request, by changing type : "POST", to type : "GET",.